# mapDispatchToProps, dispatch and axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

ok, so i have the following code and i just need some guidance as i feel this is somewhat wrong or can be refactored. It all works ok, but have some concerns about having dispatch in the register.js and the return dispatch in the action.js. To me if looks like the registerUser in actions.js is being dispatched, but i don't think i need to, a dispatch should only be performed within the catch.

Any advise would be great (also need this code to be testable)

register.js

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  registerUser: (userData, history) => dispatch(registerUser(userData, history))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withRouter(Register));
```

actions.js

```
export const registerUser = (userData, history) => {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios
      .post('/api/users/register', userData)
      .then(res => history.push('/register-complete'))
      .catch(err =>
        dispatch({
          type: GET_ERRORS,
          payload: err.response.data
        })
      );
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would do something like this:

In register.js

```
import { regiserUser } from "./actions";

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { registerUser: registerUser }
)(withRouter(Register));
```

I think this way the syntax is much cleaner, and there's no `dispatch`; see [this](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-using-mapdispatchtoprops-shorthand-notation) for more information.

And in actions.js, using the `async / await` syntax (more info [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es-2017-learn-async-await-by-example-48acc58bad65))

```
return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: USER_REGISTRATION_STARTED
    });

    try {
        await axios.post('/api/users/register', userData);

        history.push('/register-complete')

        dispatch({
            type: USER_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS
        });
    } catch (e) {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_REGISTRATION_ERROR,
            payload: {
                error: e
            }
        });
    }
};
```

With dispatching the `USER_REGISTRATION_STARTED` action you could also show a feedback (just like a loading spinner) to the user that something is going on; furthermore this way I think it's more structured.

1. Registration started
2. Registration error
3. Registration success

Hope it helps.